# Here api, RouteFeatureWeightType in Mobile SDKs

Tags: here-api

Rest Api has the option to set a "weight" (`RouteFeatureWeightType`) for every `RouteFeatureType`, while mobile SDKs have only on/off feature(es: you can ask a route with or without dirt road). Is there a similar function or workaround for mobile SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

RouteRestrictions options to specify restrictions for route calculations. These include avoidSeasonalClosures, avoidAreas.

> developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk/api_reference/Structs/RouteRestrictions.html
>
> developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/api_reference/com/here/sdk/routing/RouteRestrictions.html

More features for routing are as follows :

> developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk/api_reference/Routing.html